# How to sum up categories in Excel

Tags: excel, grouping

I am new to Excel and have a question.

I have a set of columns as follows:

```
Amount  Category
10  A
15  A
20  B
25  B
15  A
```

And I need to sum it up and get the following result:

```
Category    
A   40
B   45
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your first table and second table are set in worksheets named table1 and table2, then write the formula below in B2 cell in table2

`=sumifs(table1!A:A, table1!B:B, A2)`

Comment: Thanks pcw - I found the answer - sumif or sumifs does the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Another option, if you will be doing this repeatedly and might have a larger number of categories, would be a Pivot Table.  Select your range, or a single cell in the range, then

Insert  ► Pivot Table

Drag Category to the Rows area; Amount to the Values area; format to taste:

[image]

Comment: But pivot table will make file very fat.

Answer (score 3):

OK - Found the answer:

```
=SUMIF(D4:D8, "A", C4:C8)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2013 there will be a "grouping" option.

1. Select your table.
2. Go to the Data tab.
3. Click Structure > Grouping.

Then you can apply the sum function.

Alternatively, you can use Subtotal

You can also do this with the Subtotal feature.

1. Select Data tab
2. Click the Sort button and sort by category
3. Click the Subtotal button

Comment: I prefer pivot table.